# CSV file cleaning using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have .CSV file with four columns how to get the clean data using python pandas:

```
"a","b","{\"dtdId\":\"discussion/1\",\"value\":\"<co-content><text>abc </text></co-content>\"}","d"
```

it is taking `{\"dtdId\":\"discussion/1\"` as 3rd column and moving the data

New to python please help me out the the code

Comment: Hello. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You have to try by yourself and show what you have tried. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Since I do not know what you don't understand, I can only point you toward the [pandas `read_csv` function documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: What is the exact expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) directly setting `escapechar='\\', header=None` as parameters:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', escapechar='\\', header=None,
                 quotechar='"', , sep=','  # default parameters
                 )
```

Output:

```
   0  1                                                                              2  3
0  a  b  {"dtdId":"discussion/1","value":"<co-content><text>abc </text></co-content>"}  d
```

Reproducible demo:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

csv = io.StringIO(r'''"a","b","{\"dtdId\":\"discussion/1\",\"value\":\"<co-content><text>abc </text></co-content>\"}","d"''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, escapechar='\\', header=None, quotechar='"', , sep=',')

print(df)
```

Comment: I was misled by the html code inside the (`.csv`) file being rendered by SO.

Comment: @Timeless I had a doubt after your edit, thinking I read it incorrectly ;)